# Prove this equivalence in defining complement subspaces without contraposition

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $U,V \subset W$ be vector subspaces. Then $U$ and $V$ are complements means
$$
U\cap V = \{0\} \land W = U + V := \{z \in W |\ \exists x \in U\ \exists y \in V(z = x+y)\}  \tag{I}
$$
or equivalently
$$
\forall z \in W\ \exists ! x \in U\ \exists ! y \in V (z = x+y) \tag{II}
$$
What I want is to prove the equivalence of the two statements.

I $\to$II:
So for any $z \in W$ there are $x \in U$ and $y \in V$ with $x + y = z$. To prove uniqueness let $x' \in U, y' \in V$ be such that $x+y = x' + y' = z$. Then $U \ni x - x' = y' - y \in V$. But $U\cap V = \{0\}$, that implies $x - x' = y'- y = 0 \iff x = x' \land y = y'$.

II $\to$I:
So for any $z \in W$ there are $x \in U$ and $y \in V$ with $x + y = z$. To prove $U\cap V = \{0\}$, I proceed to show the contraposition, which is the same argument above but in the reverse. Assume $U\cap V \neq \{0\}$, then there is $0 \neq w \in U,V$. Then $z = x + y = (x+w) + (y-w)$, which is the negation of uniqueness $!$.

But is there another way, not contraposition, to prove the last thing, namely $ !\implies\cap = \scr O $ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $w\in U\cap V$.

Then $0=w+(-w)$ with $w\in U$ and $-w\in V$, but also $0=0+0$.
So, by uniqueness we obtain $w=0$.