# Direct Sum. Given a subspace, is the complement unique?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am reading some proofs and I realized that if I have this lemma below,
it will make my life easier, meaning it may simplify some of the proofs.

But I tried proving it (without talking about bases of $U, W_1, W_2$), and I couldn't prove it so far.

Now I am starting to wonder if it's true in general, or if it's true only if $V$ is finite-dimensional. Here it is.

---

**Proposition/Lemma:**

Let $V$ be e linear space and $U, W_1, W_2$ are subspaces of $V$

such that

$$V = U \oplus W_1  \quad \text{and} \quad V = U \oplus W_2$$

Then $W_1 = W_2$

---

As I said, I got a bit confused. Is this statement true for any $V$?
Or is it true only if $V$ is finite-dimensional? Or is it maybe not true at all?

Comment: If get it correctly, this Lemma doesn't hold. Take $V =\mathbb R^2$ and $U$ to be the $x$-axis and $V_1$ to be $y$-axis and $V_2$ to be the subspace $x=y$. It is clear the $U\oplus V_1 = U\oplus V_2=\mathbb R^2$ but $V_1 \neq V_2$. So the complement is not unique

Comment: @Physor So you're saying it's not true, even if $V$ is finite dimensional?

Comment: Yup! exactly. Correct me if I understood your question wrong. Because it is too late here. Anyway you have about 11.6 k Reputation, I'm confused that such a simple fact is not known to you. I don't mean to be rude or offensive!

Comment: @Physor It's too late here too. No problem. Thanks. I just get completely confused sometimes regardless of my reputation or of anything else :) I think your counter-example works here.

Comment: So complements of nontrivial proper vector subspaces are never unique. If one has an inner product then there is a special complement called *the* orthogonal complement, which is unique

Comment: @Physor The proofs I am reading are exactly about some properties of the orthogonal complement. So I thought I may use this lemma as a shortcut in those proofs, if I would manage it to prove it. Apparently the authors of the book don't use it for a reason. It's just not true. Thanks again.

Comment: @Physor "So complements of nontrivial proper vector subspaces are never unique" >>> If you could prove this statement here these days, and write it as an answer here, I would accept it gladly. Only if you want, of course. The counter example is enough for me as of now. I will also think about it, I may be able to prove it myself (at least for the case of a finite-dimensional $V$). In any case, that statement is exactly the eye-opener I needed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $V$ be real or complex vector space (honestly I don't know what other fields one can assume), and $U \subsetneq V$ a nontrivial subspace and $W$ a complement of $U$, i.e.
$$
V = U \oplus W \iff (V = U + W)\land(U \cap W  = \{0\})
$$
see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4496254/prove-this-equivalence-in-defining-complement-subspaces-without-contraposition).

Let $\{a_i\}$ be a basis in $W$ and $u_0 \in U\backslash\{0\}$, and defined $W':= \text{span}\{b_i\}$, where $b_i = a_i + u_0$. Then one can show that

- $W \neq W'$

This is because for any $i$, we have $b_i \notin W$, since $b_i - a_i = u_0 \notin W$, ($U \cap W  = \{0\}$).

- $V = U \oplus W'$

Since $W$ is a complement then any vector $V \ni x = u + w$ for unique $u \in U$ and $w \in W$. Then
$$
x = u + \sum_i w_i a_i = \left( u_i - u_0\sum_i w_i \right) + \left( \sum_i w_i b_i\right)
$$
where in the last equality the first paranthesis is in $U$ and the second in $W'$. The uniqueness of this decomposition comes from the uniqueness mentioned above and the uniqueness of the representation by a basis.